What are the odds that a hand of 5 cards can match a given double-twelve domino?
Suppose you draw a hand of 5 cards from a deck of 104 standard playing cards (two 52 card decks shuffled together) and you also draw a random domino from a set of double twelve dominos (each face can be blank or 1-12). The hand matches the domino if it can play a pair of cards that match both of the domino's faces (Ace = 1, Kings are wild and can match with any domino face. Blank faces are also wild and can match with any card). What are the odds of this occurring in a single draw? What if the hand is a different number of cards?
I don't have much combinatorial training so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to count this elegantly. I attempted to calculate it for a hand of 2 cards by bifurcating over all cases, supposing to start no wild cards or faces and ignoring replacement in the deck of cards.
Split 1, 1st card matches 1st face:
($1/12$ yes)($11/12$ no)
Split 2: 1st card matches 2nd face:
(($1/12$ yes)($11/12$ no)) (($1/12$ yes)($11/12$ no match))
Split 3: 2nd card matches the remaining face
((($1/12$ match)($11/12$ no match))(($1/12$ match)($11/12$ no match)))((($1/12$ match)($11/12$ no match))(no match))
Total: $(\frac{1}{12})^3 + (\frac{1}{12})^2(\frac{11}{12}) + (\frac{1}{12})^2(\frac{11}{12}) = 1.33\%$
I'm sure there must be an easier way to handle all these cases and subcases but I don't know it.

I would approach it differently, having the cases reflect the two cards drawn out of $~104.~$  Either the two cards represent a pair (two cards of the same rank), or they don't.  If the cards are a pair, either this is a pair of kings or it isn't.  If the two cards are not a pair, either one of the two cards is a king, or neither card is a king.

There are four cases to consider: the domino is one of [0-0], [0-x], [x-x] or [x-y], with x and x being distinct positive values.

Hint: count the hands that don't match the domino.

Addendum added to the end of my answer to show adjustments to the $~g(k)~$ function, since there are only $~91~$ dominoes, rather than $~169~$ dominoes.

I am assuming that there are $~(12 + 1)^2 = 169~$ different dominoes, where the left face of the domino can be blank or run from 1 through 12, and ditto the right face of the domino.
If the original poster (instead) intends that there are only $~91~$ dominoes, because (for example) there is only one [blank :: 1] domino, rather than two [blank :: 1] dominoes, then the original poster should leave a corresponding message following my answer.  Then, I will add an Addendum that re-computes.
I think that when attacking this type of combinatorics-oriented probability problem, it is best to strive for expressing as much as the analysis as possible combinatorically, as I do in this answer.
To facilitate this type of attack, I think it best to create cases based on the nature of the 2 cards out of 104 cards that are drawn.
So, there are $~4~$ cases:

Event $~E_1:$ 
The two cards are a pair (the same rank) but are not kings.

Event $~E_2:$ 
The two cards are a pair of kings.

Event $~E_3:$ 
The two cards are not a pair and neither card is a king.

Event $~E_4:$ 
The two cards are not a pair and one of the two cards is a king.


For $~k \in \{1,2,3,4\},~$ 
let $~f(k)~$ denote the probability of event $~E_k~$ occurring, and 
let $~g(k)~$ denote the probability of a match, given that event $~E_k~$ occurred.
Then, the desired computation is
$$\sum_{k=1}^4 \left[ ~f(k) \times g(k) ~\right], \tag1 $$
so the problem reduces to computing $~f(k)~$ and $~g(k),~$ for each $~k~$ in $~\{1,2,3,4\}.$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~f(k)}$
When computing $~f(k),~$ the sample space is $\displaystyle \binom{104}{2}.~$
To compute $~f(1),~$ note that there are $~\displaystyle 12 \times \binom{8}{2}~$ ways of choosing which non-kings rank will be involved, and then choosing two of the 8 cards from that rank.   So,
$$f(1) = \frac{12 \times \binom{8}{2}}{\binom{104}{2}}.$$
Similarly,
$$f(2) = \frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{104}{2}}.$$
To compute $~f(3),~$ you have to choose 2 distinct non-king ranks, and then choose 1 card from each rank.  So,
$$f(3) = \frac{\binom{12}{2} \times 8^2}{\binom{104}{2}}.$$
To compute $~f(4),~$ you have to choose 1 distinct non-king rank, and then choose 1 card from each rank.  So,
$$f(4) = \frac{\binom{12}{1} \times 8^2}{\binom{104}{2}}.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~g(k)}$
When computing $~g(k),~$ the sample space is $~13^2 = 169.$
To compute $~g(1),~$ you can assume, without loss of generality, that both of the cards are Aces.  So, you need a domino where each face is either blank, or a 1.
Therefore,
$$g(1) = \frac{4}{169}.$$
To compute $~g(2),~$ since both kings are wild cards, you are guaranteed a match.  Therefore,
$$g(2) = 1.$$
To compute $~g(3),~$ you can assume, without loss of generality, that one of the two cards is an Ace, and the other card is a Deuce.  The list of satisfying dominoes is
[blank::blank], [blank::1], [blank::2], [1::blank], [2::blank], [1::2], and [2::1].
Therefore,
$$g(3) = \frac{7}{169}.$$
To compute $~g(4),~$ you can assume, without loss of generality, that one of the two cards is an Ace, and the other card is a King.
If either face of the domino is blank, then (because of the presence of the King), the domino satisfies.  There are $~25~$ such dominoes.
Temporarily excluding those $~25~$ dominoes from consideration, the domino will satisfy if and only if at least one of the two faces is a 1. There are $~23~$ additional satisfying dominoes.
Therefore,
$$g(4) = \frac{25 + 23}{169}.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Adjustments made to the $~g(k)~$ function, since there are only $~91~$ dominoes, rather than $~169~$ dominoes.
When computing $~g(k),~$ the sample space is $~91.$
To compute $~g(1),~$ you can assume, without loss of generality, that both of the cards are Aces.  So, you need a domino where each face is either blank, or a 1.
The list of satisfying dominoes is
[blank::blank], [blank::1], [1::1].
Therefore,
$$g(1) = \frac{3}{91}.$$
To compute $~g(2),~$ since both kings are wild cards, you are guaranteed a match.  Therefore,
$$g(2) = 1.$$
To compute $~g(3),~$ you can assume, without loss of generality, that one of the two cards is an Ace, and the other card is a Deuce.  The list of satisfying dominoes is
[blank::blank], [blank::1], [blank::2], and [1::2].
Therefore,
$$g(3) = \frac{4}{91}.$$
To compute $~g(4),~$ you can assume, without loss of generality, that one of the two cards is an Ace, and the other card is a King.
If either face of the domino is blank, then (because of the presence of the King), the domino satisfies.  There are $~13~$ such dominoes.
Temporarily excluding those $~13~$ dominoes from consideration, the domino will satisfy if and only if at least one of the two faces is a 1. There are $~12~$ additional satisfying dominoes.
Therefore,
$$g(4) = \frac{13 + 12}{91}.$$

This is amazing! I think this is definitely the elegant method I was looking for; I didn't know which cases to split into to make for the easiest calculation. As for your original question: I do intend there to be only 91 dominos; there should be just one domino with a blank face and a single pip face.

@Rob Addendum added to the end of my answer to show adjustments to the $~g(k)~$ function, since there are only $~91~$ dominoes, rather than $~169~$ dominoes.
